# jquery function ready only when tab opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I use some tabs according to twitter bootstrap tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

In my last tabs, there are some functions that call ajax and give burden to my website. Maybe user never opens the last tab. I prefer that ready functions of my jquery wait for only when that tab opened.
I know there are some ways, but is there any clean way to simulates ready only when last tab was selected. maybe this code expresses what I want:

```
$ run only once on when document ready and last tab opened
{
  $(function() {
     call relatex ajax loadings
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think here your choice is document ready handler.... you can use the `shown` event provided by bootstrap tabs for this purpose

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.nav-tabs a').one('show', function(e){
        //use e.target to know which tab was shown, then make the ajax requests
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if($target.attr('href') == '#profile'){
            alert('profile')
        } else if($target.attr('href') == '#messages'){
            alert('messages')
        } else if($target.attr('href') == '#settings'){
            alert('settings')
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MY54D/)

If you want to target only specific tabs then register the handler for only those `a` elements like

```
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#profile"]').one('show', function(e){
    //this will fire for only profile tab
});
```

Comment: +1, I'll just upvote yours, it's basically the same, and you where faster.